# react-router-dom v6 <Link> reloads page when certain object is passed to state

Tags: reactjs, momentjs, react-router-dom

I am currently using `<Link to={"/user/" + user.id} state={{ user }}>...</Link>` to link to the user profile page. **Via state I provide the user object.**

This is the route in question:

```
<Route
  path="user/:id"
  element={<SelectedUserTab />}
/>
```

The user object consists of multiple nested objects. **When an user has the following object in the user object that is being passed to the `<Link>` state, instead of staying within the App and showing the page, the `<Link>` is handled like a `<a>` and the /user/:id page is "hard-loaded".** (Reloading the entire app page, instead of just showing the new page)

```
timeEvents: [
  {
    start: moment("2022-03-09", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
    end: moment("2022-03-10", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
    type: "unavailable",
  },
  {
    start: moment("2022-03-14", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
    end: moment("2022-03-15", "YYYY-MM-DD"),
    type: "unavailable",
  },
],
```

Is there something in this object, that could cause `<Link>` to have an exception or smth that causes it to "hard-load" the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Resolved

✔️ **The problem for me was the presence of the Moment.js code as part of the object.**

Replacing the `start` and `end` parameters with timestamps has resolved the issue for me. The conversion to `moment()` happens later in the code, which is a good idea anyways. Using the JavaScript `Date()` function will work too.

```
timeEvents: [
  {
    start: 1646434800,
    end: 1646521200,
    type: "unavailable",
  },
],
```